# Is "My first cell phone 'was' just a phone." correct? "was or is?"

Tags: grammar

"My first cell phone 'was' just a phone..(old phone, I am now not using it anymore.)

It was quite bulky and heavy.(old phone, I am now not using it anymore.)

I am now using smartphone now.

I think, first cell phone is still just a phone and bulky and heavy.

So I think, my first cell phone is just a phone and it is quite bulky and heavy.

Answer (score 2):

Use "was", the old cell phone is not around, it is in the past.

The exception would be when you have both the old phone and new phone.

> My first cell phone was bulky. Now I have a smartphone.
>
> This is my first phone. It is big and bulky. My new phone is a smartphone.